# Google app engine to run executable files

Tags: file, google-app-engine, executable, whitelist

Is it possible to run executable files in google app engine? Like by using Runtime.exec?

There is whitelist on google app engine documentation which list classes that can be used but functions/ inside the classes are not specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, absolutely not.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that make AppEngine possible is that both the Python and Java environments are controlled by Google so that performance/scability and security issues are minimized. They don't even allow to use all the standard Java/Python classes, so imagine the problems that could arise if they let people run any executable file. One may even be a virus!