# How do i execute system commands in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to execute simple system command via my servlet on google app engine.  I'm not trying anything dangerous, just looking for simple stuff grep, sed, wget, find, etc.

Using java's Runtime class i keep getting access denied exceptions.

Do i have to get permission from google of some kind or are shell commands banned period?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152114/google-app-engine-to-run-executable-files

Comment: Whether it's dangerous or not, who says Google App Engine's servers are running on an OS which has grep, sed, wget, find, etc, installed? Or a shell? Short answer is just no, GAE doesn't provide any "system" environment. If it helps, imagine you're in an Applet-style sandbox and security manager. Google's servers don't trust you.

Comment: I know at least that google app engine i running on some flavor of linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly sure you [can't do this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox).

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> ```
> * make other kinds of system calls.
> ```