# How to communicate with an external exe program from an google cloud app engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, process

I want to make a Lichess BOT that plays chess using Stockfish engine. Stockfish has an .exe file I can run and communicate through UCI protocol. I want to write my application in node.js and deploy on google cloud app engine. I can deploy a node.js program, but how do I get stockfish.exe program to run on app engine and use it in my javascript code?

Comment: Have you considered using [stockfish.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stockfish) intead of running a .exe file? That would make it way simpler. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think it's a good solution, though I used a virtual machine on google compute engine, so I am using the exe file.

Comment: What environment are you using? Standard or Flexible?

Comment: It's Standard environment

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** in App Engine Standard.

The reason for that is that the environments in App Engine are controlled by Google so that performance/scability and **security** issues are minimized. And enabling executables to be executed in such environment could pose a high security risk.

For the Flexible environment you have a bit more flexibility with the use of Docker Files, and this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38899355/12857703) might be helpful on that regard, however, I would say that this is still not recommended.